SpringBoot - Websockets STOMP 1.2 - How to detect and log heart-beat from client and from server
How do I capture and log STOMP heart-beats sent by the clients and by the server?
I have SpringBoot configuration below for websockets using STOMP
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("-api-heartbeat-thread-");
        taskScheduler.initialize();

        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
                        .setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{25000, 25000})
                                .setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/api");

    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}


A client should send a heart-beat every 25 seconds (25000 milliseconds). How can I capture and log this heartbeat in Spring Application?

The server is also supposed to send a heat-beat to the client every 25 seconds. How can I console.log(); this heart-beat in a Javascript application?


I might be missing something but I have searched extensively and could not find a solution.
